# GNU emacs: setting keybindings to highlight text with shift key

Tags: emacs, lisp, key-bindings

I'm trying to set some keybindings to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to highlight text. I could use `pc-selection-mode`, but that doesn't offer all the key bindings I want. For example, I'd like to be able to shift-mark an entire paragraph by pressing <kbd>Shift-Ctrl-down</kbd> which I can do in most MS text editors, but `pc-selection-mode` doesn't allow you to do this.

I found this [website](http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/past/shift_mark/EmacsShiftMark.html) which has a [`shift_mark.el`](http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/past/shift_mark/shift_mark.el) file I can use to set all the key bindings I want. I've put in my `.xemacs/init.el` file to load `shift_mark.el`.

This is the error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/theory/phrkaj/\
.xemacs/init.el':

Wrong type argument: arrayp, (shift right)
```

So I've run Emacs with `--debug-init` to try and find the problem. This is what the debugger came up with:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument arrayp (shift right))
  signal(wrong-type-argument (arrayp (shift right)))
  global-set-key((shift right) shift-mark-forward-char)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<3>> nil "/home/theory/phrkaj/shift_mark.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1476
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/theory/phrkaj/shift_mark.el" "/home/theory/phrkaj/shift_mark.el" nil nil)
  load("~/shift_mark.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*<2>> nil "/home/theory/phrkaj/.xemacs/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 25
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/theory/phrkaj/.xemacs/init.el" "/home/theory/phrkaj/.xemacs/init.el" nil nil)
  load("/home/theory/phrkaj/.xemacs/init.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/home/theory/phrkaj/.xemacs/init.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/theory/phrkaj/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 253
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/theory/phrkaj/.emacs" "/home/theory/phrkaj/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\264^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\2027^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\2027^@\312\307\313\316#\203/^@\317\2027^@\315\2027^@\307^H\320Q^Z\321^S\322\n\321\211#\210^K\321=\203_^@\323\324\325\307^H\326Q!\"^\\322\f\$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Here's part of the `shift_mark.el` file which defines the highlighting of one char forward:

```
(defun shift-mark-forward-char ()
  (interactive)
  (shift-mark 'forward-char))

(global-set-key '(shift right) 'shift-mark-forward-char)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? Your post looks inconsistent between GNU Emacs and XEmacs. Also, under XEmacs 21 with no setup on my part and with GNU Emacs 23 with `pc-selection-mode`, `Ctrl+Shift+Down` does work as you require. Does it work for you if you start `emacs -q` or `xemacs -q` (i.e. without loading your configuration file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under GNU Emacs, the key binding should look like

```
(global-set-key [(shift right)] 'shift-mark-forward-char)
```

(`[…]` constructs a literal array). But I suspect you're going at this the wrong way. Are you running GNU Emacs, XEmacs, or both? What versions? Unless you're running extremely old versions, `pc-selection-mode` should do what you want under GNU Emacs, and no setup should be required under XEmacs. If you run both GNU Emacs and XEmacs, you can use the following code in your `.emacs`:

```
(defvar running-xemacs (string-match "XEmacs" emacs-version))
(if (not running-xemacs)
    (pc-selection-mode 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `shift-select-mode` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> shift-select-mode is a variable defined in `simple.el'.
>   Its value is nil
>
> Documentation:
>   When non-nil, shifted motion keys activate the mark momentarily.
>
> While the mark is activated in this way, any shift-translated point
>   motion key extends the region, and if Transient Mark mode was off, it
>   is temporarily turned on.  Furthermore, the mark will be deactivated
>   by any subsequent point motion key that was not shift-translated, or
>   by any action that normally deactivates the mark in Transient Mark mode.
>
> See `this-command-keys-shift-translated' for the meaning of
>   shift-translation.
>
> You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced in GNU Emacs 23.1:

> ** Temporarily active regions
>
> *** The new variable shift-select-mode, non-nil by default, controls
>   shift-selection.  When Shift Select mode is on, shift-translated
>   motion keys (e.g. S-left and S-down) activate and extend a temporary
>   region, similar to mouse-selection.
>
> *** Temporarily active regions, created using shift-selection or
>   mouse-selection, are not necessarily deactivated in the next command.
>   They are only deactivated after point motion commands that are not
>   shift-translated, or after commands that would ordinarily deactivate
>   the mark in Transient Mark mode (e.g., any command that modifies the
>   buffer).